# Not able to POST/PUT image file from Win form application to external API

Tags: winforms

Thanks in advance for looking into my issue.

Summary of my problem

1. I have node.js external API that I am consuming in my win form application using HttpClient
2. I have one end point that Edit seller detail
3. Data that I will post to API have both text and file (eg sellerName - text data, sellerLogo - Image file)
4. sending text data + file(seller logo) to api don't work
5. Invoking API end point from postman and sending data plus file works
   Please find images to my code that I currently have.

Postman Screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV7N1.png)

Application code1 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvM8M.png)
Application code2 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nIZm.png)

I will like to able to send data along with image file to external api end point

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below is working code
[Working code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I8SZ.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).